# How to set dimensions of LineSeries

Tags: oxyplot, lineseries

I have a line series that covers data from 1 to 20 along the X axis and 0 to 1 along the Y axis. My problem is that the x axis always starts at 0 and goes to the furthest value and the Y axis starts at 0 but only goes to the furthest value as well. How can I set these dimensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for the Y axis this is what you want

```
plotModel.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis()
        {
            Title = "Y axis Name",
            Position = AxisPosition.Left,
            MinorStep = 0.1,
            FilterMinValue = -1,
            FilterMaxValue = 1
        });
```

As for the X axis it seems to be more annoying handLabeling seems to be the only way.

```
plotModel.Axes.Add(new CategoryAxis() 
        {
           Title = "X axis name",
           Position = AxisPosition.Bottom,
           Labels = {"1","2","3","4","5","6" } // ... upto 20
        });
```

Then every item you add index the value of the Category label.
For example if I want an column of 64 on 3 in X axis then the code would look like this:

```
var item =new ColumnItem(62, 2); // index 2 being value "3"
```